# Codeigniter create schema

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

How can I automatically create tables in database if they don't exists yet? I need something like installation library for creating database tables at first run of application.

Answer (score 2):

Their Database library has the 'forge'.

`$this->load->dbforge()` to load the library, then you have methods for creating database, tables, add columns, create and fill fields, adding records and so on.
Check [Database Forge USer Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html)  for a complete list of methods.

Comment: how can I run creating tables procedure? I dont think that it is good idea to write a database checking in each controller. may be there is something like bootstrap in CI?

Comment: @Molfar You may want to use hooks for that (but after the DB has been initialized, of course). Anyway, usually creating the db schema happens the first time you ever install the application, so you may have a install.php files that checks and builds tables, then prompt the user to delete it and start loading it normally,as many systems do

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter now has database Migrations, this uses the dbforge library in a more controlled way for malipiating the database

Check out the [Docs here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html).
Also this handy [tutorial](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/how-to-implement-database-migrations.html)

Comment: There is no longer the need to load _dbforge_ in the up function of the migration (as the tutorial is doing). We can invoke `$this->dbforge->create_table` directly once migrations are enabled in _config/migration.php_.